# Trigger UIMenu item programmatically

Tags: swift, uimenuitem

How can we press a UIMenu item programmatically?

I want to trigger the 'Copy' item programmatically to open its submenu (Simulate the user press). Is there a way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Which menu is this? How did you open the parent menu programmatically in the first place?

Comment: The menu is triggered by a user pressing a UIButton. My goal is to programmatically select a particular item from the menu list after its presentation, which will, in turn, open its submenu.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documents, Apple did not provide anything to allow this.  The object is no related to `UIView` or `UIControls`, so the commonly used behaviors inherited from `UIRespodner` are not available.

> Responder objects — instances of UIResponder — constitute the event-handling backbone of a UIKit app...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder#overview